# If you have a object's orientation in an image, how do you find its translation?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, robotics

I am attempting to estimate 6DOF pose of CAD models from a single image. The models are of simple, reflective objects (i.e. variously cut metal rectangular prisms). Using pose estimation code, I have its orientation in Euler angles but no translation. The images are incredibly simple, only the object on a monochromatic background, so they are easily segmented.

Challenges and Constraints:

- The approach has to be generic enough to work on "simple" shapes like rectangular prisms and pyramids for example.
- The objects are highly reflective and the location of their light source may change.
- It does not need to be quick, but it does need to be within 10% of the actual value.
- All the objects have well defined corners.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you show us some examples? How do you define the translation? From where to where?

Comment: if you can find those corners in  order you'll be able to apply cv2.findHomography  and then cv2.decomposeHomography to get  rotation , translation matricies

Comment: You cannot recover the translation, unless you know the object's size a-priori, or the size of a different object in the same scene. This is because scale is lost in projection: the monster in the 1933 King Kong movie looked quite impressive, event though it was a doll 24 in tall.